# self submit form and cookie PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

I have a form that gets information from a database, after a user registers they are sent to a page where they make selection from radio buttons, after each selection I want to save the selection "10 in total" the first time the page show, the first selection shown and after that nothing. $count stay at 1 "not increment" can someone look at my code and tell me why.

```
<?php       
if(isset($_COOKIE['counter'])){
    $count = isset($_COOKIE['counter']);
    print($count);
}
else{
    $count = 1;
    print("Shouldn't see this after first click");
}

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "worldcup2014db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$querySelection = "SELECT * from teamselections where id = '$count'";

$resultSelection = mysqli_query($connection , $querySelection);

        print("<form method='post' action='selection.php'>");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSelection)){
            $t1 = $row['team1id'];
            $t2 = $row['team2id'];
            $t3 = $row['team3id'];
            $t4 = $row['team4id'];



                if($row['teamid'] == $t1){
                    $tName1 = $row['name'];
                }
                if($row['teamid'] == $t2){
                    $tName2 = $row['name'];
                }
                if($row['teamid'] == $t3){
                    $tName3 = $row['name'];
                }
                if($row['teamid'] == $t4){
                    $tName4 = $row['name'];
                }                   
            }

            print("<input type='radio' id='rd1' name='teamname' value='$t1'>$tName1</input>");
            print("<input type='radio' id='rd2' name='teamname' value='$t2'>$tName2</input>");
            if($count > 4){
                print("<input type='radio' id='rd3' name='teamname' value='$t3'>$tName3</input>");
                print("<input type='radio' id='rd4' name='teamname' value='$t4'>$tName4</input>");  
            }

            print("<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Continue\">");                            
        }
        $count++; // increment count
        print("</form>");

        setcookie('counter', $count);
        print($count);

        mysqli_close($connection);
```

?>

[image: screenshot of when page loads first]

[image: screenshot after continue is clicked, count set back to 1]

[image: screenshot of cookie setting in browser]

thanks in advance

Gman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$count++;` is outside the `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSelection)){` loop

Like so:

```
        print("<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Continue\">");  
        $count++; // increment count                          
    }
    print("</form>");
```

And as @Devon stated, third line should read:

```
$count = $_COOKIE['counter'];
```

Comment: Also, his `$count = isset($_COOKIE['counter']);` isn't printing the count but is showing if count is set.  It should be `$count = $_COOKIE['counter']`.

Comment: Thks.. added it the the anwser

Comment: I did have it inside but made no difference so put it outside, have moved it back inside the while loop and still the same.

Comment: Check the third line.. the count wasn't assigned correctly.

Comment: @Gman isset() will only return 1 (if the variable is set) or 0 if the variable isn't set.  You weren't printing the value of the counter.

Comment: Thanks guys, spent the last 2 hours on that. @Devon $count = $_COOKIE['counter'] WORKED. thanks a mill.